# Gitlab via SSH can connect via IP Address but not when using the FQDN

Tags: gitlab

I am currently stuck on an error in git using gitlab 14.10.4. I can `ssh -T git@IP_ADDRESS` but not `ssh -T git@FQDN`. I am using the same key, same machine where I can connect to git via ssh on ip address. What am I missing?

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:VX3JDVrZYNtFpFUhiQR11IYdRCotA/yl/H0DodwKqRY agent
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:VX3JDVrZYNtFpFUhiQR11IYdRCotA/yl/H0DodwKqRY agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@fqdn: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

my setup would be gitlab server is proxied on a separate web server. but I already tried attaching the ip address directly on the gitlab server and still encounter the same error where I can connect to the gitlab server via ssh on ip address, while not via FQDN.

Comment: Are you sure that the FQDN points to the same machine as the IP address?

Comment: Yes @TangentiallyPerpendicular , I tried pinging the FQDN and the machine ip address shows. Also I can visit my gitlab server via IP address and via fqdn on browser